# How the linkWithCredential works? How does it work with Rules?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I found this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) that explains about how to link anonymous user with a new registered user, but I couldn't understand how it works.

From the explanation also found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking), I got a big picture like below (*please correct me if I'm wrong*):

1. User login with anonymous: got userUid (just for example) `ANONYM-USER-UID`
2. User than add data to shopping cart like below:

data

```
-- shoppingCart
    -- ANONYM-USER-UID
       -- <push-id>
          -- itemUid: <item-uid>
          -- count: 2
       -- <push-id>
          -- itemUid: <other-item-uid>
          -- count: 1
    -- OTHER-USER-UID
       -- .......
```

with rule: **Only appropriate UserId can access shopping cart**

```
"rules": {
   "shoppingCart" {
       "$userUid": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == $userUid"
       }
   }
}
```

3. Before checkout, user "forced" to register/or login, the `AuthCredential` then retrieved then `linkWithCredential` called. User than use a new userUID for example `REGISTERED-USER-UID`

The question is, whenever the client code query `shoppingCart/REGISTERED-USER-UID` will it retrieve the item list of `shoppingCart/ANONYM-USER-UID`? Will the Rule allow it?

What if a more complex rule is applied, for example, the rule becomes 
-- **Only appropriate UserId can access shopping cart, but userUid must not in blackList child**.

```
"rules": {
   "shoppingCart" {
       "$userUid": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == $userUid && root.child('blackList').child($userUid).val() == false"
       }
   }
}
```

With a logical restriction like that, will it successfully return the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are slightly confused regarding the flow of **Anonymous-User login** and then **linking it with new Auth Credentials.** Here is what I have experienced.

When a user logs in as anonymous then **system assigns a unique ID.** Now when the user decides to sign up with some new auth credentials **then all that happens is that previous UID generated at time of anonymous login gets assigned or** **linked** to *those new credentials.*

So ***in reality no new UID is created*** and you are good to go.

Do let me know if this info was helpful.

Comment: Thanks thats explain a lot

Comment: although it's worth pointing out that you don't get first and last name from google and store them on the anonymous user. You may need to do some work to update names.